# Naming of links line in social media

Tags: hyperlinks, social-media, social-interfaces

In many social media applications there are lines of links or buttons, such as **favorite, share, like** etc.

Sometimes there have additional information such as the number of times an action has been taken against it.

Some examples

[image: Pocket]

[image: Facebook]

With an expanded extra links icon

[image: Twitter]

A variation, links are in a list view

[image]

Question:

What is this called in the UX world (links bar?) and does the variations above have different names also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **Actions** to that particular post/card/list-item. The actions will differ from application to application but the basic philosophy is to make it easier and granular for the user to perform the action for a particular element such as a Facebook Status.

They are specifically used to perform an important action.

As a design principle, the actions which are **Primarily used** and are **Positive** are used before the **Not Oftenly Used** actions.

Negative Actions are generally buried in the Overflow Menu, to indicate lesser importance and to avoid accidental destructive actions such as Delete.

Comment: Would a line of actions be referred to as an "action line" or still just "actions" ?

Comment: Actions. Since every element is separate.